# Detectar silencio en Liquidsoap + Icecast2 y cambiar a playlist

Tags: liquid

Uso Icecast2 con Liquidsoap y deseo ver si alguien me puede ayudar a solucionar un inconveniente en el código.
Deseo que cuando el DJ emita un silencio por +10 segundos que comience la playlist que tengo seteada por defecto.
Lo que he logrado es que si el DJ corta el encoder se active la playlist a los 10 segundos, pero si el DJ por descuido se le terminan sus canciones y emite un silencio (teniendo activo su encoder) que comience la playlist hasta tanto no emita una nueva canción, esto no funciona con mi código.

```
# Settings
# settings.server.telnet := true
# settings.server.telnet.port := 8595
settings.log.level := 3
settings.harbor.bind_addrs := ["0.0.0.0"]
settings.log.file := true
settings.log.file.path := "/home/icecast2/liquidsoap/log/registro.log"

# SSL certificate configuration
transport = http.transport.tls(
  # Server mode: required,
  # client mode: optional, add certificate to trusted pool
  certificate="/etc/letsencrypt/live/myradio.com/fullchain.pem",
  # Server mode: required, client mode: ignored
  key="/etc/letsencrypt/live/myradio.com/privkey.pem",
)

# Environment Variables
password_dj=environment.get("PASSWORD_DJ")
password_inv1=environment.get("PASSWORD_INV1")
password_inv2=environment.get("PASSWORD_INV2")
password_inv3=environment.get("PASSWORD_INV3")
source_passw=environment.get("SOURCE_PASSW")
port_https=environment.get("PORT_HTTPS")
port_live=environment.get("PORT_LIVE")
port_inv1=environment.get("PORT_INV1")
port_inv2=environment.get("PORT_INV2")
port_inv3=environment.get("PORT_INV3")
host_https_no_prot=environment.get("HOST_HTTPS_NO_PROT")

# Convert string to integer
port_live_int=int_of_string(port_live)
port_https_int=int_of_string(port_https)
port_inv1_int=int_of_string(port_inv1)
port_inv2_int=int_of_string(port_inv2)
port_inv3_int=int_of_string(port_inv3)

# Definir la fuente original de la lista de reproducción y aplicar nrj
original_playlist_source=playlist("~/music/playlist.pls")
original_playlist=nrj(original_playlist_source)

# Aplicar crossfades a la playlist
original_playlist=crossfade(fade_out=3.0, fade_in=3.0, original_playlist)

# Security fallback
security_source=single("~/music_security/security.mp3")
playlist_securitized=fallback(track_sensitive=false, [original_playlist, security_source])

# Support for live streams
live=input.harbor(
    "live",
    port=port_live_int,
    password=password_dj,
    replay_metadata=true,
    icy_metadata_charset="UTF-8"
)
inv1=input.harbor(
    "inv1",
    port=port_inv1_int,
    password=password_inv1,
    replay_metadata=true,
    icy_metadata_charset="UTF-8"
)
inv2=input.harbor(
    "inv2",
    port=port_inv2_int,
    password=password_inv2,
    replay_metadata=true,
    icy_metadata_charset="UTF-8"
)
inv3=input.harbor(
    "inv3",
    port=port_inv3_int,
    password=password_inv3,
    replay_metadata=true,
    icy_metadata_charset="UTF-8"
)

# Fallback for live and music playlists with silence detection
radio = fallback(track_sensitive=false, [
    live,
    inv1,
    inv2,
    inv3,
    strip_blank(max_blank=10., playlist_securitized)# It will automatically switch to the playlist after 10 seconds of silence
])

# Stream it out MP3
output.icecast(
    %ffmpeg(format="mp3", %audio(codec="libmp3lame", b="192k")),
    radio,
    mount="stream",
    name="My Radio",
    description="foo",
    fallible=true,
    host=host_https_no_prot,
    port=port_https_int,
    password=source_passw,
    transport=transport,
)
```

Liquidsoap v. 2.2.0

Icecast2 v.2.4.4

Ubuntu 22.04

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar